# Microphone not working in Asus F555U

Tags: 14.04, sound, asus, microphone

The microphone is not working in Asus F555U in Ubuntu 14.04 and kernel 4.2.0-27-generic. By running the command `arecord -l` I have found the following:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have searched and tried in vain to fix this issue.

Issue can be found here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1447909 and also here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304274

Please help resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=laptop-dmic
```